# Extracting URL from javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, jsoup

I have a following problem.
I am using jSoup to extract an image from page (I am trying to download manga), and then go to the next page, to download next image and so on...
Normally, I extract URL to next page from a button:

```
<a href="2.html" class="btn next_page"><span></span>next page</a>
```

but when one chapter of the manga ends, and when I click the button on page, it's redirecting me to next chapter through JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="next_chapter()" class="btn next_page"><span></span>next page</a>
```

Is there some way to extract the link to next page? Someone before suggested me Selenium, and I tried few times and failed. Maybe someone have any suggestions?

Ok, so here's my code snippet:

```
while (endManga) {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
            String title = doc.title();
            System.out.println(title);

            Element nextButtonDiv = doc.getElementById("top_center_bar");
            Elements nextButton = nextButtonDiv.select("a[href]");
            if (nextButton.isEmpty())
                endManga = true;
            else {
                Element nextLinkElement = nextButton
                        .get(nextButton.size() - 1);

                String nextLink;


                //here is the problem - at some point, when one chapter ends, 
                //there isn't link to the next one, only "onclick="next_chapter()"" javascript function


                if (nextLinkElement.attr("href").length() < 10)
                    nextLink = nextLinkElement.attr("abs:href");
                else
                    nextLink = nextLinkElement.attr("href");

                link = nextLink;
            }
            Element content = doc.getElementById("viewer");
            Elements jpgs = content.select("img[src$=.jpg]");

            BufferedImage image = null;

            if (jpgs.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("empty!!");
                counterVolume++;
            } else {
                for (Element imageURL : jpgs) {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageURL.attr("src")));
                    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("manga/"
                            + counterVolume + "_" + counterPage++ + ".jpg"));
                    System.out.println("zgrane - volume: " + counterVolume
                            + " , page: " + counterPage);
                }
            }
        }
```

An here's my code, where I used selenium:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("link_to_page_with_javascript_function");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("top_center_bar"));
    List<WebElement> el = element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println(element.getTagName());

    for(WebElement e : el){
        if(e.getText().equals("next page")){
            //here I have the button, which clicked redirects me to next chapter
            //how can I extract the link from this function??
            e.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to figure out the URL of the next page **before** clicking on the element?

Comment: @Louis I was under the impression that this question was specific to Javascript instead. Sorry if that was wrong, feel free to revert if you think it is appropriate.

Comment: I don't want to click it at all. I want to get the URL without opening the browser. I want to get link to extract next image using jSoup from the next page. I don't know if you get it;p if not, i'll include code snippet to my app.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL structures are consistent, you could manually construct the correct URL just by knowing that you've hit the end of the chapter, as a special case of your extraction algorithm.

```js
if (endOfChapter) {
  url = 'chapter-' + newChapterNum + '/1.html'; // first page of new chapter
}
```

I know this isn't a generalized solution but depending on the scope of your application it may be all you need.

Comment: Nope, unfortunatelly it's not consistent at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple solution without actually letting selenium do the work. However, I see these possibilities:

1. if you look at the source code you may understand the JavaScript function and remodel its workings in Java. If it loads something form the Net you may need to look at the Traffic that is created by the click. Without having the source that you want to get I can't be more specific.
2. Use Selenium and the click() as you have done. Then just get the loaded URL back from selenium. The method you are looking for is called `driver.getCurrentUrl()`. Of course it would be maybe easier to take the source of the page (`driver.getPageSource()`) and feed it back to JSoup and go an then with your regular JSoup approach.

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="link-to-the-next-page.html" onclick="next_chapter()" class="btn next_page"><span></span>next page</a>
```

Then

```
var next_chapter = function next_chapter(ev){
  ev.preventDefault() ;
  var linkToTheNextPAge = this.href ;
  doSomething(linkToTheNextPAge) ;
}
```

onclick will be executed and the link will not follow.
If I were you, I would do this using eventListener

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting negative votes. The op didn't specify enough when I posted it and before he edit the original question, it was a valid answer at the moment for what he was asking and for the way he was programming.